# UWP Toast works, but images (AdaptiveImage, ToastGenericHeroImage, ToastGenericAppLogo) not displaying

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I am targeting Windows 10, latest OS build.  I copy/pasted some stuff from the Microsoft adaptive toast examples--including the paths.  Here's my code:

```
public void CreateToast(ToastViewModel model)
{
    ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
    {
        Launch = "app-defined-string",

        Visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
            {
                Children =
                {
                    new AdaptiveText()
                    {
                        Text = "Photo Share"
                    },

                    new AdaptiveText()
                    {
                        Text = "Andrew sent you a picture"
                    },

                    new AdaptiveText()
                    {
                        Text = "See it in full size!"
                    },

                    new AdaptiveImage()
                    {
                        Source = "https://unsplash.it/360/180?image=1043"
                    }
                },
                HeroImage = new ToastGenericHeroImage()
                {
                    Source = "https://unsplash.it/360/180?image=1043"
                },
                AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo()
                {
                    Source = "https://unsplash.it/64?image=883",
                    HintCrop = ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var toast = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
    toast.Failed += (o, args) =>
    {
        var message = args.ErrorCode;
    };

    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}
```

The toast displays, but the images do not.  Anyone have an idea?

---

**EDIT:** As @AVK suggested I decided to give it a shot using XML instead; unfortunately I get the same behavior -- toast shows, but no images.  Here's my code for that (though admittedly I know even less about XML, so this code could be wrong-er):

```
var template = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02;
var xml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(template);
var elements = xml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
var text = xml.CreateTextNode(model.Title);
elements[0].AppendChild(text);
var images = xml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
var srcAttribute = xml.CreateAttribute("src");
srcAttribute.Value = "https://unsplash.it/64?image=883";
images[0].Attributes.SetNamedItem(srcAttribute);
var toast = new ToastNotification(xml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Comment: does this work when you create actual xml?

Comment: @AVK good question; I'll check that out

Comment: @AVK updated with XML example

Comment: Did you declare the 'internetClient' capability in your appx manifest?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I have Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client), and Private Networks (Client & Server).  Would there be a different one I'd need?

Comment: @codeMonkey are you creating a Centennial Win32 app? Or a normal UWP project?

Comment: @AndrewBares normal UWP

Comment: Can you downloading the [Notifications Visualizer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1) app, switch to the toasts page, and try popping the `PhotoTagged.xml` notification from there? Do the images appear then?

Answer (score 6):

Http images are only supported in Desktop Bridge apps that have the internet capability in their manifest. Classic Win32 apps do not support http images; you must download the image to your local app data and reference it locally.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows 10 bug that causes Toast Notification for applications to not show images.

[Run the troubleshooter for Windows apps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027498/windows-10-run-the-troubleshooter-for-apps) could fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to share by chance about the bug?

Comment: @codeMonkey Unfortunately, I did not find any useful details about this bug, which is why I will find this StackOverflow page.